# Startup Disk Creator - not found in Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: software-center, startup-disk

I am trying to create a bootable USB startup disk in 20.04

According to instructions, I should use "Startup Disk Creator". But this application does not appear to be installed on my machine. So to Ubuntu Software Centre, but a search there only give the message application not found.

Where is it then?

Comment: Press left windows key and type "startup" in the search box

Comment: Interesting, on my 20.04, the package `usb-creator-gtk` whose alias is "Startup disk creator" is provided through the `ubuntu-focal-main` repository, which is THE default source for new software... (Also, I believe it was installed by default, because I have it installed, but I don't remember installing it.)

Answer (score 6):

If you are comfortable using the command line, you can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

Note:

On my system, I have two "software centers" installed.

1. Software
2. Ubuntu Software

When I search for "Startup Disk Creator" in either of these, I do get a listing for this application. I am also able to search using "usb-creator-gtk", and I get a result.

Try searching for "usb-creator-gtk". If you don't get a result, there may be another issue on your system.

However, executing the (`apt`) commands above will show you if there is another underlying error.

Comment: Can confirm, on 20.04, Ubuntu Software lists it both by the names "Startup disk creator" and by `usb-creator-gtk`. Its source is `ubuntu-focal-main`. (And I believe it was installed by default, because I have it installed and I don't remember installing it.)

Answer (score 0):

You ask about the specific software, but I hope there is enough room here to point out that you do not necessarily need that software.

I have created my live USB installer with the terminal's copy utility (the `cp` command).

I have taken that guidance from here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_medium#Using_basic_command_line_utilities

(This guide contains guidance for other CLI utility procedures too, like `cat`, `dd`, and `tee`. I picked `cp` because it seemed the least complicated.)

An excerpt of the above would amount to the following:

- **Be aware that this procedure will destroy all data on the USB stick that it previously contained.**
- After you have plugged in the USB stick, use the `lsblk` command to determine its identifier (e.g. `sdx` or something like that — replace the here symbolically used **`x`** to the actual letter your system indicates).
- Make sure it's not mounted.

  - If the system has automounted it for you, then unmount it with the `umount` command.
- Use the `cp path/to/ubuntu-desktop-image.iso /dev/sdx` command to copy the image to the USB stick.

  - Make sure that you specify the entire device and not a partition on it:

    - That's done by ensuring that the identifier does not end with a number:

      - `sdx1`: not good
      - `sdx`: good

In case the resulting USB installer does not seem to work, it's worth attempting the procedure at least once more, before trying with something else.